# Testing whether sums of cubes are Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, time-limit-exceeded, fibonacci-sequence

I'm trying to iterate through all the combinations of pairs of positive `long` integers in Java and testing the sum of their cubes to discover if it's a Fibonacci number. I'm currently doing this by using the value of the outer loop variable as the inner loop's upper limit, with the effect being that the outer loop runs a little slower each time. Initially it appeared to run very quickly--I was up to 10 digits within minutes. But now after 2 full days of continuous execution, I'm only somewhere in the middle range of 15 digits. At this rate it may end up taking a whole year just to finish running this program.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;

public class FindFib
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  long uLimit=9223372036854775807L;   //long maximum value
  BigDecimal PHI=new BigDecimal(1D+Math.sqrt(5D)/2D);  //Golden Ratio

  for(long a=1;a<=uLimit;a++)    //Outer Loop, 1 to maximum
   for(long b=1;b<=a;b++)     //Inner Loop, 1 to current outer
   {
    //Cube the numbers and add
    BigDecimal c=BigDecimal.valueOf(a).pow(3).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(b).pow(3));
    System.out.print(c+" ");  //Output result
    //Upper and lower limits of interval for Mobius test: [c*PHI-1/c,c*PHI+1/c]
    BigDecimal d=c.multiply(PHI).subtract(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(c,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)),
     e=c.multiply(PHI).add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(c,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    //Mobius test: if integer in interval (floor values unequal) Fibonacci number!
    if (d.toBigInteger().compareTo(e.toBigInteger())!=0)
     System.out.println();    //Line feed
    else
      System.out.print("\r");    //Carriage return instead
   }
  //Display final message
  System.out.println("\rDone.                                                                                 ");
 }
}
```

Now the use of `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` was deliberate; I need them to get the necessary precision. Is there anything other than my variable types that I could change to gain better efficiency?

Comment: cache the powers. fill an array with the cubes from 1 to your limit. and don't recalculate them in the nested cycle.

Comment: @ra2085 interesting idea, but how much memory does an array of `BigInteger` with 9223372036854775807 elements require?

Comment: It'd probably be easier to optimize this at the algorithm level, and not the code level.  This is as bruteforce as you're going to get, and you may get some wins by reducing the math instead of worrying about programming overhead.

Comment: It's in beta, but that doesn't mean it's a good site to post to. Lots of good advice going on there if you have a good question. And it seems to be doing [pretty well](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review)

Comment: hehe, a lot, but you can always do it in batches. Divide and conquer!

Comment: @Makoto is right, I can't remember if this problem is one of the "Euler Project" optimization ones.

Comment: you can also limit your iterations by calculating the fibonacci seres first hand (non recursive of course) and then only test those numbers.

Comment: @ra2085 Mobius' test is pretty efficient. More efficient perhaps than creating an array with the Binet formula.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the order of your loops.

Loop over the Fibonacci numbers - there is only `O(log N)` of these less than N.

Then loop down from to `cbrt(N)` to `cbrt(N/2)` looking for the highest of the two cubes in its sum.

Comment: Wouldn't it be inefficient to invent my own cube root algorithm that works with BigInteger or BigDecimal?

Comment: Also I would need an efficient way to generate the Fibonacci sequence. It just seemed like the better option to use the Mobius test on the individual cases of sums of cubes, even though there's more of them.

Comment: You can generate the Fibbonacci numbers sequentially using the usual `F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}` in this case - you wont get much faster than that ;)

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink It might be sufficient to approximate the cube root with a few iterations of Newton's method or something, because the search space savings are almost certainly worth it

Comment: @user3580294 I could also buffer the previous two Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Sorry, I don't quite follow. Is that an additional optimization?

Comment: @user3580294 since I would be checking each Fibonacci for a sum of cubes individually, I would only need to keep it for 3 calculations. No need to store them all in a list, just have, say array[3], and shift the values over each time. I could make a cache of my cubes, though.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink Oh, I see. Yes, not storing all the Fibonacci numbers you're calculating with would be useful indeed. I was talking about something else, though. I was trying to suggest a way to implement a `cubeRoot()` function/approximation without burning too many CPU cycles.

Comment: @user3580294 I will use it. I'm already familiar with the version for the square root; the cube root isn't much different. Gonna really miss the magic of the Mobius test, though.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I have to agree that it's a pretty interesting result; it's rather unfortunate that using it requires the rest of the algorithm to be suboptimal though...

Comment: @user3580294 I just saw why you were confused. I read the comment above yours and tagged you in the reply by mistake.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I could also buffer the previous two Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson since I would be checking each Fibonacci for a sum of cubes individually, I would only need to keep it for 3 calculations. No need to store them all in a list, just have, say array[3], and shift the values over each time. I could make a cache of my cubes, though.

Comment: Looping *down* from `cbrt(N)` to `cbrt(N/2)` to find the *larger* item of a pair of cubes will be more efficient (by a factor of almost 4) than looping up . . .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your code will ever finish executing. Just looping from 1 to Long.MAX_VALUE (Convenient way to get long's max value) will take a stupid amount of time, even if you do no calculation:2^63 - 1 iterations, lets assume 1 billion per second. = 9223372036 seconds = 292 years. And thats with a billion per second, just one loop, not two. BigDecimals are slow, and the inner loop basically squares the amount of time it will take...

If you ever decide to lower your limit and make it a bit more feasible, do what a commenter said and precalculate the cubes, instead of doing it again and again in the inner loop. This would probably save a significant amount of time, as BigDecimals are quite slow. If you did your cubing with BigIntegers it might be faster. Even with these optimizations, you will never finish with the current max value.

If you ever do want this to run even faster, I would suggest programming it in C++ using the GMP library for highly optimized arbitrary precision math. You could even write some C++ and then use it from java with JNI.